# Submit using enter key and prevent submitting empty text

Tags: javascript

I need to submit a form when I press enter key but this code submits when I am still typing my message. It should let me finish typing and hit enter to submit, but not allow it to submit if the text is blank.

```
(function() {
    var age = document.getElementById('age');
    age.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if (age.value > 20) {
                document.getElementById('post').click();
            } 
        }else {
                document.getElementById('post').click();
            }
    });
}());
```

And also check this to add multiple key code for shft + enter to allow me continue my message.

```
var done = disabled;
if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('post').click();
else if(e.keyCode==16 && e.keyCode==13)document.getElementById('post').disabled == done;`
```

Answer (score 1):

you are submitting in `if` and `else`, no matter what the key pressed is you submit the form. Remove else:

```
(function() {
    var age = document.getElementById('age');
    age.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
       if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if (age.value > 20) {
                document.getElementById('post').click();
            } 
       }
    });
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not run `document.getElementById('post').click();` unless the keystroke is an enter. You can fix this by just removing the else statement in your code.